# How to open link in new tab on submit

Tags: html, forms, url, tabs, submit

I have a form like the following:

```
<form action='<?=BASE_PATH?>hostel-details' method='GET'>

    <input type='hidden' name='hname' value='<?php echo $hostels['name'];?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='city' value='<?php echo "$citi" ;?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='date_st' value='<?php echo "$startdate" ;?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='date_end' value='<?php echo "$enddate" ;?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='num' value='<?php echo "$Num" ;?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='propnum' value='<?php echo "$propNum" ;?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='guestnum' value='<?php echo $guests?>'>

    <a href='#' onclick='this.parentNode.submit()'>More Info</a>
</form>
```

When I click on 'More Info', the link is opening on the same page.

If I add the `target="_blank"` attribute, the link opens in a new tab but not in current tab.

But I want the link to open both in the current tab and in a new tab.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: why do you want to open up the same thing in 2 windows?

Comment: user can open the link in the same tab or tab,if the user open the link in new tab he can check all remaining links until the first one load.

Comment: please tell me is there any way to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot force a link to open in a new tab. This can only be controlled by the user, or settings in the browser.

Even large sites like Travelocity settle for opening several new windows when they do something like this.

Comment: in Travelocity user can open the new tab by the link,I need to be able to do that to be able to open multiple windows like Travelocity.